# Webpage not rendering the same way in WebBrowser control, works fine in Mobile IE

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I got a strange issue. I'm currently using a WebBrowser control in my app to do some Facebook Connect. I'm not using the Facebook SDK because it doesn't suit my needs.

Here is the issue : inside a WebBrowser control in the app, some elements (ie the text, images , a select list) doesn't show/work ! Though they work fine with Mobile IE (same URL etc...).

I tried to use the exact same User Agent Mobile IE use, no change.

Any idea of why this difference ?

Thanks

---

Here are some pictures :

**From IE :**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm6Ku.png
**From the app :**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/egNNi.png

---

Here is the code (pretty standard) :

```
void browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as WebBrowser).Navigate(new
Uri("http://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,publish_actions"),
null, "User-Agent: Mozilla 5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.5; Windows Phone 8.0;
Trident/6.0; IEMobile/9.5; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 725)");
}
```

The User-Agent header has the same value as Mobile IE, but it's useless it makes NO difference.

Comment: Can you confirm the URI you're connecting to and all the headers that are being sent

Comment: @MattLacey Added the code. But it's really really standard code. I'm just navigating to an url... The strange thing is the difference in rendering outside of IE...

Comment: @SonerGönül I feel sorry for you if you don't know how to make a webbrowser control navigate to an url. I added the code anyway.

Comment: Can you show the resulting HTML in both cases (rather than pictures or the code to navigate with the control)? Is it the same HTML and the control just behaves differently or is the response from FB different?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That was not the problem, but you made me fix it. I answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Guys, I fixed it...

This is a really stupid problem : by default scripts are disabled in the WebBrowser control.

I just added this :

```
    void browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as WebBrowser).IsScriptEnabled = true;
    }
```

And no more issue. Facebook login page is mostly rendered via javascript calls I guess.

Thanks for the help !